# Cannot use object of type Closure as array Mqtt::ConnectAndSubscribe Laravel

Tags: laravel, mqtt

I am trying to build a notification service in my laravel+angular application using mqtt

while testing mqtt on laravel I got the error "Cannot use object of type Closure as array"

Here is my code: (error is coming on line where I call Mqtt::ConnectAndSubscribe

```
//topic, function, client_id
        Mqtt::ConnectAndSubscribe("User".$toUId, function($topic, $msg){
            \Log::Debug("Msg Received, topic: ".$topic." , message: ".$msg);
        }, "User".$uId);

   
            \Log::Debug("sending mqtt message");
            //$obj = json_encode(["msg" => "test message", "type" => "call", "from" => $uId]);
            $obj = "dummy message";
            //$output = Mqtt::ConnectAndPublish($topic, $message, $client_id);
            $output = Mqtt::ConnectAndPublish("User".$toUId, $obj , "User".$uId);
            if($output) {
                \Log::Debug("Message sent");
            }
```

My logs:

```
[2021-03-12 06:44:43] local.ERROR: Cannot use object of type Closure as array {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Cannot use object of type Closure as array at /home/sudhanshug/ws/hytech/EVA-video-call/backend/vendor/salmanzafar/laravel-mqtt/src/MqttClass/MqttService.php:172)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/sudhanshug/ws/hytech/EVA-video-call/backend/vendor/salmanzafar/laravel-mqtt/src/MqttClass/Mqtt.php(107): Salman\\Mqtt\\MqttClass\\MqttService->subscribe()
#1 /home/sudhanshug/ws/hytech/EVA-video-call/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261): Salman\\Mqtt\\MqttClass\\Mqtt->ConnectAndSubscribe()
#2 /home/sudhanshug/ws/hytech/EVA-video-call/backend/app/Http/Controllers/APIController.php(146):
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you cannot use callback check this https://github.com/salmanzafar949/MQTT-Laravel/blob/17b8830e6987701bd3c6050cbb4f52de111d5728/src/MqttClass/Mqtt.php#L71  it accept only `ConnectAndPublish($topic, $msg, $client_id=null, $retain=null)`

Comment: @KamleshPaul I am getting error in ConnectAndSubscribe

Comment: public function ConnectAndSubscribe($topic, $proc, $client_id=null)